# Unnest grab keywords/nextwords/beforewords function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, loops, nlp

**Background**

I have the following code to create a `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
word_list = ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels']
l = ['there are many different crayons in the bright blue box and crayons of all different colors',
     'i like a lot of sports cars because they go really fast'
    'the middle east has many camels to ride and have fun',
    'all camels are fun']
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Text'])
```

the `df` looks like this

```
    Text
0   there are many different crayons in the bright blue box and crayons of all different colors
1   i like a lot of sports cars because they go really fastthe middle east has many camels to ride and have fun
2   all camels are fun
```

The following code works and creates a function that grabs the `trigger` words, along with words that come before (`beforewords`) and after (`nextwords`) the `trigger` words

```
def find_words(row, word_list):

    sentence = row[0]

    #make empty lists
    trigger = []
    next_words = []
    before_words = []

    for keyword in word_list:
        #split words
        words = str(sentence).split()

        for index in range(0, len(words) - 1):

            # get keyword we want
            if words[index] == keyword:

                # get words after keyword and add to empty list
                next_words.append(words[index + 1:index + 3])

                # get words before keyword and add to empty list
                before_words.append(words[max(index - 3, 0):max(index - 1, 0)])

                # append
                trigger.append(keyword)

    return pd.Series([trigger,  before_words, next_words], index = ['Trigger', 'BeforeWords','NextWords'])

# glue together
df= df.join(df.apply(lambda x: find_words(x, word_list), axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
    Text         Trigger                  BeforeWords             NextWords
0   there ...    [crayons, crayons] [[are, many],[blue, box]] [[in, the],[of, all]]
1   i like ...   [cars, camels]     [[lot, of], [east, has]] [[because, they], [to, ride]]
2   all camels... [camels]             [[]]                  [[are, fun]]
```

**Problem**

However, I would like to *either*  1) unstack 2) unlist *OR* use another/better way to get the following

**Desired Output**

```
Text             Trigger        BeforeWords     NextWords
0   there ...    crayons        are many        in the 
1   there ...    crayons        blue box        of all
2   i like ...   cars           lot of          because they
3   i like ...   camels         east has        to ride
4   all camels...camels                         are fun
```

**Question**

How do I tweak my `find_words` function to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like unnesting , so we can using

```
s=df.set_index(['Text']).stack()
s=pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index).stack()
s.apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x) if type(x)==list else x).unstack(1).reset_index(level=0)
                                                Text      ...          NextWords
0  there are many different crayons in the bright...      ...             in the
1  there are many different crayons in the bright...      ...             of all
0  i like a lot of sports cars because they go re...      ...       because they
1  i like a lot of sports cars because they go re...      ...            to ride
0                                 all camels are fun      ...            are fun
[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: This works great on my toy dataframe example listed above. But when I apply the same code to my real dataframe, I get the following error `
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found` . Any thoughts on how I can fix?

Comment: @ER_18 can you check the different between your real df and sample df ?

Comment: difference in terms of data type within the real df?

Comment: @ER_18 yep , the data structure is different , so that the solution may different

Comment: when I use `df.info()` for the actual `df` that I am using it returns the following: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> Int64Index: 419 entries, 137665 to 49388  Data columns (total 6 columns): dtypes: object(6)`. Does this help?

Comment: And when I do `df.info()` on the sample df I get `RangeIndex` instead of `Int64Index`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @ER_18 that is not the issue ..I think the columns may contain some edge situation

Comment: anything else I can do to figure out the problem? any other suggestions?

Comment: @ER_18 running the code line by line , check which line return the error code