# use a custom function to find all words in a column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, function

**Background**

The following question is a variation from [Unnest grab keywords/nextwords/beforewords function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826420/unnest-grab-keywords-nextwords-beforewords-function).

**1)** I have the following `word_list`

```
word_list = ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels']
```

**2)** And `df1`

```
l = ['there are many crayons, in the blue box crayons that are',
     'cars! i like a lot of sports cars because they go fast',
     'the camels, in the middle east have many camels to ride ']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Text'])

df1
         Text
0   there are many crayons, in the blue box crayons that are
1   cars! i like a lot of sports cars because they go fast
2   the camels, in the middle east have many camels to ride
```

**3)** I also have a function `find_next_words` which uses `word_list` to grab words from `Text` column in `df1`

```
def find_next_words(row, word_list):

    sentence = row[0]

    trigger_words = []
    next_words = []

    for keyword in word_list:

        words = sentence.split()

        for index in range(0, len(words) - 1):
            if words[index] == keyword:
                trigger_words.append(keyword)
                next_words.append(words[index + 1:index + 3]) 

    return pd.Series([trigger_words, next_words], index = ['TriggerWords','NextWords'])
```

**4)** And it's pieced together with the following

```
df2 = df1.join(df.apply(lambda x: find_next_words(x, word_list), axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
    Text           TriggerWords        NextWords
0                   [crayons]        [[that, are]]
1                   [cars]           [[because, they]]
2                   [camels]         [[to, ride]]
```

**Problem**

**5)** The output misses the following

`crayons,` from row `0` of `Text` column `df1`

`cars!`    from row `1` of `Text` column `df1`

`camels,`  from row `2` of `Text` column `df1`

**Goal**

**6)** Grab all corresponding words from `df1` even if the words in `df1` have a slight variation e.g. `crayons,` `cars!` from the words in `word_list`

*(For this toy example, I know I can easily fix this problem by just adding these word variations to `word_list = ['crayons,','crayons', 'cars!',`cars`, 'camels,', 'camels'].` But this would be impractical to do with my my real word_list, which contains ~20K words)*

**Desired Output**

```
Text           TriggerWords              NextWords
0               [crayons, crayons]  [[in, the], [that, are]]
1               [cars, cars]        [[i,like],[because, they]]
2               [camels, camels]    [[in, the], [to, ride]]
```

**Questions**

How do I 1) tweak my `word_list` (e.g. regex?) 2) or `find_next_words` function to achieve my desired output?

Comment: What if the word come at the end of line ?

Comment: do you mean the word in `Text` column? e.g.  `cars!` in   `i like a lot of sports cars because they go fast cars!`  If so, this is fine too. The above `Text` is just a toy example. The word can be found anywhere (begining, middle, end)

Comment: What will be desired output if string is something like `hello some test string cars` ??

Comment: The issue would be if `cars` had an extra character hanging at the end e.g. `cars?`. In this sting  `hello some test string cars` my code above should work. It should return `cars` under the `TriggerWords` column and return `[ ]` under the `NextWords` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nltk
```

change

```
words = sentence.split()
```

to

```
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

this leads to

```
'crayons', ','
```

instead of

```
'crayons,'
```

which allows `find_next_words` to correctly identify all words from `word_list` in `Text` column

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your regex something like this

```
\b(crayons|cars|camels)\b(?:[^a-z\n]*([a-z]*)[^a-z\n]*([a-z]*))
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/8niSUB/10)

Comment: where would `\b(crayons|cars|camels)\b(?:$|[^a-z\n]*([a-z]*)[^a-z\n]*([a-z]*))` be used in my code above? Would it be used in `word_list =\b(crayons|cars|camels)\b(?:$|[^a-z]*([a-z]*)[^a-z]*([a-z]*))` ?

Comment: @ER_18 You can do something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/8niSUB/10/codegen?language=python)

Comment: I figured out the issue. Your answer was really close to what I wanted. Thank you.